# why does urllib2 return 500?

Tags: python

I'm trying the following -

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://dviappvmtca01:9001/deploy/?jobname=\blah12345')
print page.getcode()
```

I can open that site in my browser and with httpfox and I get/see a 404.  If I try from python with the script above I get the following dump -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen('http://dviappvmtca01:9001/deploy/?jobname=\blah12345')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Comment: `\b` is probably being treated as a "backspace" metachar, not "backslash and B". Try `\\b`?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant snippet of the server's log file and/or error log file?

Comment: the string problem... oh i really wish there is a similar difference between " and ' in python to in perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib2.urlopen` returns a 500 because, to quote [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.1), "*The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request*."

The log files of the server might provide information about why the server returned 500.

Comment: corrected.  I have the urllib2.open return coming as 404 now.  the problem was in the code on my API.